# Nette getHttpData include of unchecked checkboxes

Tags: forms, checkbox, nette

can somehow unchecked checkboxes be included when I have a form with a dynamic number of checkboxes (`name='golyPenalta[]'`) and in submit I get them using `$form->getHttpData($form::DATA_TEXT, "golyPenalta[]");` ? Only the ones that have been checked are placed in the field and have their own order, so I do not know which penalty belongs to which goal:

```
golyCas => array (3)
   0 => "55" (2)
   1 => "60" (2)
   2 => "70" (2)
golyPenalta => array (2)
   0 => "on" (2)
   1 => "on" (2)   // <- this should be part of third goal so index should be 2
```

I already tried to do it with `$form->getHttpData($form::DATA_TEXT | $form::DATA_KEYS, "golyPenalta[]");` but with no luck. The dump above is from the dump of `$form` in attribute httpData.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually made it with specific key in input name `name='golyPenalta[key]'` when I create dynamic numbers of this field. It can be done either way by Nette form `name='golyPenalta[{key}]'` or I create it by JavaScript in for loop when I get the number of fields I have to create like this `name='golyPenalta[$i]'`.

In form submit I use `$form->getHttpData($form::DATA_TEXT | $form::DATA_KEYS, "golyPenalta[]")` to persist these keys.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no, unchecked checkboxes aren't even sent in POST data in http. You have to define the elements in nette and then use `$form->getValues()` to have them included. If you add them just on the client side, the server has no chance to know they exist.